# Using Jeremy Mcanally's context for testing in Rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, tdd

I'd like to try out Jeremy Mcanally's context gem for testing:

http://github.com/jeremymcanally/context/tree/master

It does not work out of the box with Rails 2.3.x, anyone got it working?

EDIT

> hi mike, tx for ur help. i installed the gem like u said, and have added "require 'context'" to test_helper.rb however, it stil doesn't seem to b behaving correctly. the followin unit test is failing as @truth is nil.

```
context "a simple truth" do
  before do
    @truth = true
  end

  test "the truth1" do
    assert @truth
  end
end
```

any idea?

EDIT
screw it... i installed shoulda
http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/tree/master
even just for the context blocks (for now anyway) and it's working great.

Comment: I tried context with one of my 2.3.4 projects and it's working with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found...

Did you download the source from github.com or `gem install context`? If the latter, then start off with a `gem uninstall`, because whatever the rubygems context is, it ain't Mr Macanally's one!

Once you have the source, unzip (or untar) it somewhere and in that directory, run `gem build context.gemspec`, which for me produced a file named `context-0.5.5.gem`. Now you can do 'gem install context-0.5.5.gem' and you have the right library installed.

Last thing to do is to tell your tests about the new gem. I added `require 'context'` to `RAILS_ROOT/test/test_helper.rb` and bingo!

That's what worked for me, at least.